# Apache Beam KafkaIO Processing stuck at readfromkafka

Tags: java, database, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read from a Kafka topic using Apache Beam, Google Dataflow.
Here's the code:

```
public class readkafka3 {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Readkafka.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(
        PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

        PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KV<String, String>>> kafka =
                KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                    .withBootstrapServers("masked")
                    .withTopic("simple-avro-kafka-golang")
                    .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .withMaxNumRecords(5)
                    .withoutMetadata();
        p.apply(kafka)
            .apply(Values.<String>create())
            .apply(TextIO.write().to("gs://sg-dataflow").withSuffix(".csv"));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward string topic.
However, Google Dataflow logs return

```
2019-10-09T11:20:32.287Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-4 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:32.302Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-5 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:32.316Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-6 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:32.388Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-7 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.111Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-0 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.184Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-1 to offset 2. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.198Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-2 to offset 1. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.212Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-3 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.284Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-4 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.301Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-5 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.315Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-6 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:33.388Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-7 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:34.111Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-0 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:34.184Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-1 to offset 2. 
2019-10-09T11:20:34.198Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-2 to offset 1. 
2019-10-09T11:20:34.213Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-3 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:34.285Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-4 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:34.300Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-5 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:34.314Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-6 to offset 0. 
I 2019-10-09T11:20:34.386Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-7 to offset 0. 
I 2019-10-09T11:20:35.111Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-0 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:35.186Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-1 to offset 2. 
2019-10-09T11:20:35.200Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-2 to offset 1. 
2019-10-09T11:20:35.215Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-3 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:35.287Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-4 to offset 0. 
2019-10-09T11:20:35.302Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-5 to offset 0. 
I 2019-10-09T11:20:35.316Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-6 to offset 0. 
I 2019-10-09T11:20:35.388Z [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=Reader-0_offset_consumer_1300992802_my_beam_app_1] Resetting offset for partition simple-avro-kafka-golang-7 to offset 0. 
I 2019-10-09T11:20:36.082Z Proposing dynamic split of work unit mudah-analytics-222509;2019-10-09_04_16_05-6447123281517054755;6616295919164789357 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
2019-10-09T11:20:36.082Z Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source.
```

And it goes on and on. It just keeps repeating reseting offset for partition.
Eventually, logs return processing stuck at step reading from kafka.

```
Processing stuck in step KafkaIO.Read/KafkaIO.Read/Read(KafkaUnboundedSource)/Read(AutoValue_BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource_UnboundedToBoundedSourceAdapter) for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340) at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:386) at
```

Please note that I am not the one who produced the kafka topic, that is done by the infra team.
I am a data engineer trying to read from the topic.
It seems I've hit a deadlock or an infinite loop ?

[logs1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LllaV.png)

[logs2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDYaW.png)

[logs3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgyQQ.png)

Thanks

Comment: Did you use `withMaxNumRecords(5)` intentionally?  It makes KafkaIO work as bounded source.

Comment: yes I did as you see in the code, that is what confuses me

Comment: Does it work for If you remove `withMaxNumRecords(5)`? Probably, it can be caused by this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6466

Comment: Can you post full log? Or especially first couple of minutes of logs on the worker would be useful. Even if it is a network issue between Dataflow worker your Kafka cluster, it should have descriptive error about it in the log.

Comment: I added the full logs as imgs in my post. I doubt its a connection issue because I am in fact able to read from some topics in this kafka cluster, but some other topics I am not able to. Hence, I suspect its a topic issue

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko It does not work as well

Comment: It will wait until 5 records are available. Lower `withMaxNumRecords` to 1.